# CVS file add/del

Tags: cvs

I have scheduled some files to remove in CVS but have not commited the same.
Now I don't want to remove those files. What should I do? 
To commit file addition/deletion, we use cvs commit. Whats the opposite of cvs commit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cvs add` on the file to resurrect it; it will be copied from the repository to your working directory, and the removal/addition will not show up in your next commit.

Comment: BTW: CVS is a decades-old, low-quality source control system which you should avoid if at all possible. There are a dozen better alternatives.